# Auto copy one form field to another but only up to a certain character

Tags: jquery, html, forms

[UPDATE]

I have tried Clives solution (thanks), it doesnt seem to work for me.

I am using the following form code

```
<form>
Email: <br /><input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" /><br />
Name: <br /><input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" />
</form>
```

and have updated Clives code to the following

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
           $('#name').bind('focus', function() {
  if ($(this).val() == '' && $('#email').val() != '') {
    var emailPart = $('#email').val().split('@')[0];
    $(this).val(emailPart);
  }
});
</script>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

---

How would I go about copying one form field to another but only up to a certain character?

I would like to automatically copy everything entered in the email address field UP TO the @ symbol into the username field

e.g entering the following into the email field

```
franco@imrubbishatprogramming.com
```

would automatically populate the username field with

```
franco
```

I would like this to happen once the user clicks on the username field OR they tab to it.

Thanks very much
Si

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#id-of-username-field').bind('focus', function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '' && $('#id-of-email-field').val() != '') {
      var emailPart = $('#id-of-email-field').val().split('@')[0];
      $(this).val(emailPart);
    }
  });
});
```

That should do it

Comment: Hi Clive, thanks very much. I can't seem to get this working so have put my code in the original post in the hope you can help.

Comment: You just need to make sure the function loads when the DOM is ready, I've updated the answer to reflect that and you can see the code in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/KTF4m/1/) :-)